# How do we know that a rational function has at most 1 slant asymptote?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I was wondering why it must be the case that a rational function such as
$$f(x) = 3x + 2 + \frac{2}{x+6}$$
has only one slant asymptote. My textbook gave an intuitive explanation of why this might be true but it was far from rigorous. I understand why
$$y = 3x + 2$$
is a slant asymptote. But isn't it possible that it could have more? Could anybody explain why it must be the case that functions such as $f$ must have at most 1 slant asymptote?

Comment: Decent question.  Are you familiar with the notion of *limit*?

Comment: @Randall not really, but if your proof requires a notion of it, I will try to understand it. Of course, it would be preferable if your proof didn't contain it but if it does, please still feel free to post it.

Comment: In that case, it would be better to wait on an answer that doesn't use it.  I'm interested in seeing it myself.

Comment: I used to call these "polynomial asymptotes" when I taught precalculus. As for why at most one, suppose there were two different polynomial asymptotes. Note (or prove, depending on your background level) that the [end behavior](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22end+behavior%22+polynomial) of the **difference** of these two polynomials is not zero, so each cannot be closer than half of this "end behavior difference" to the rational function. (This was not intended to be written in a mathematically precise manner, but rather in a way that hopefully conveys the essential idea.)

Comment: Every rational function is ratio of two polynomials $f(x)=\frac{S(x)}{P(x)}$. You can find quotient and remainder from division and write $f(x)=Q(x)+R(x)/P(x)$, where degree of polynomial $P(x)$ is greater than degree of polynomial $R(x)$. Every slant asymptote must have $x$s tending to infinity. For $x$ tending to infinity $\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}$ tends to zero. Then behavior of $f(x)$ at $x$ tending to infinity is determined by $Q(x)$. If $Q(x)$ is linear, then $f(x)$ will be approaching to linear function and $y=Q(x)$ will be slant asymptote at both $x\to+\infty$ and $-\infty$

Comment: My previous comment was made when the OP originally gave a quadratic polynomial as a slant asymptote, and I didn't read any further to see if a typo or other oversight had been made. I just assumed the OP misused standard terminology, which another early comment (now deleted) also appeared to assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 types of asymptotes:

1. *Vertical*
2. *Horizontal*
3. *Slant*

So, **non vertical** asymptote can be **slant** asymptote or **horizontal** asymptote.

A function $f(x)$ can have *at most two* **non vertical** asymptotes:

1. First one is for the case when $x\to-\infty$.
2. Second one is for the case when $x\to+\infty$.

When a function has **only one** non vertical asymptote? It can happen only in these 3 cases:

1. Function $f(x)$ has asymptote for the case $x\to-\infty$, but doesn't have asymptote for the case $x\to+\infty$.
2. Function $f(x)$ doesn't have asymptote for the case $x\to-\infty$, but has asymptote for the case $x\to+\infty$.
3. Function $f(x)$ has *the same* asymptote in both cases: $x\to-\infty$ and $x\to+\infty$.

Function $f(x)=3x+2+\frac{2}{x+6}$ has asymptote $y=3x+2$ when $x\to-\infty$ since the term $\frac{2}{x+6}$ becomes very small when $x$ is very large negative number (so $f(x)=3x+2+\frac{2}{x+6}\approx 3x+2$, when $x\to-\infty$) and the degree of $3x+2$ is one, so it's a line and thus it's an asymptote (if this part would be a polynomial of higher degree than $1$ then asymptote wouldn't exist).

But it also has the same asymptote $y=3x+2$ when $x\to+\infty$ (since $\frac{2}{x+6}$ becomes also very small when $x$ is very large positive number). That's why this function has *only one* non vertical asymptote, which is *slant* asymptote in this case (it would be a horizontal asymptote if degree of the part mentioned above would be zero, i.e. it would be a constant).

**Bonus tip**: a function can have unlimited number of vertical asymptotes (for example, $f(x)=tg(x)$ has vertical asymptotes at points $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: There are also [nonlinear asymptotes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nonlinear+asymptote%22) such as [quadratic asymptotes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quadratic+asymptote%22), [cubic asymptote](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cubic+asymptote%22), etc. It is often helpful in graphing rational functions to observe that every rational function can be written as $P(x) + R(x),$ where $P(x)$ is a polynomial (might be the zero polynomial) and $R(x)$ approaches zero as $|x| \rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: The term **nonlinear asymptote** makes no sense at all since then any _equivalent_ function can be an asymptote. For example, then function $f(x)=x^2$ will have asymptotes $f(x)=x^2+1$, $f(x)=x^2+2$, $f(x)=\sqrt{x^4+3}$, $f(x)=\ln(e^{x^2}+3)$, etc. (functions f and g are _equivalent_ as $x\to a$ if $\underset{x\to a}{\lim}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$)

Comment: Whether or not it makes sense, the term "nonlinear asymptote" is often used. However, as I said in a comment elsewhere, I preferred the term "polynomial asymptote" (which restores uniqueness). Incidentally, $\underset{x\to \infty}{\lim}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ (I assume you meant $\infty$ instead of $a)$ is the concept of [*asymptotic equivalence*](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Asymptotic_equivalence) (other terms also used), whereas to be an asymptote we require the stronger property that $\underset{x\to \infty}{\lim}[f(x)-g(x)]=0.$ **(continued)**

Comment: Of course, if non-polynomials are involved, we can still lose uniqueness. For more about various types of "limiting equivalences", see [this 22 March 2003 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/S7X-C-FglaQ/m/Xhlkm6ii3dMJ).

Comment: No, I didn't mean just the case $a=\infty$. For example, functions $\sin(x)$ and $x$ are _equivalent_ as $x\to 0$ since $\underset{x\to 0}{\lim}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}
=1$. "Polynomial asymptote" still doesn't guarantee uniqueness (for example, $x^2+1$ and $x^2+2$ are polynomials and are equivalent to $x^2$ as $x\to\infty$). For polynomials $\underset{x\to \infty}{\lim}|f(x)-g(x)|=0$ implies that $f(x)=g(x)$, but then it has nothing to do with asymptotics.

Comment: The words "asymptote" and "asymptotic" are different and also differently used. The former is when the difference approaches zero and the latter is when the quotient approaches one.

Comment: Indeed, _asymptote_, _asymptotic_ and _asymptotics_ are 3 different words and have different meanings (I disagree with _your_ definitions of some of them though). I've used _asymptotics_ (not _asymptotic_).